# ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

Tags: javascript, java, angular, angularjs

In this code, I have an error that says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')"

```
lowPassword(control: FormControl): {
  [lowLevelPassword: string]: boolean;
} {
  if (this.invalidPassword.indexOf(control.value) != -1) {
    return {
      lowLevelPassword: true,
    };
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  is ```this.invalidPassword``` defined?

Comment: yes this is about it

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: is this java or javascript?

Comment: this is javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

invalidPassword is a array like => [{id: 1, name:'john'}]
control.value is a key like => control.value = name

if there is name like key in invalidPassword array it return true otherwise false

Example:

(control.value in invalidPassword) ? 'available' : 'none'